# MySQL Replication is Not Working Master Slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I am new to MySQL and tried to create replication
Here are my.cnf on Master

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/logs/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=fedorareptest1
server-id=1
----
```

My.cnf on Slave

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

server-id=2
master-host=130.14.165.25
master-connect-retry=60
master-user=reptest
master-password=nopass!123
replicate-do-db=fedorareptest1
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/logs/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/logs/slave-relay-log.index

--------
```

Note: The database mentioned in "replicate-do-db=fedorareptest1" is the database on the master. This database name on the slave is fedoratest2. Should I use this above or it should be the one on master

When I do Slave status:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 130.14.165.25
                  Master_User: reptest
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 107
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay.000005
                Relay_Log_Pos: 252
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: fedorareptest1
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 107
              Relay_Log_Space: 549
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
--------------------------------------
```

When I do update on the table the row does not show up on the slave!

PLEASE HELP AND I AM NEW TO MYSQL.

Comment: Please post the query that you are using for the update

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the *do-db options, as they can [cause problems](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/)

Check that the queries are coming through to your slave:

```
mysqlbinlog --short-form /path/to/relaylogfile | less
```

.. or ..

```
tcpdump -vv -A -i lo0 tcp port 3306 | tee dump.log
```

**UPDATE** having reread your post I noticed the issue: you have change the DB name and not used [replicate-rewrite-db](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db)

Comment: I ran the command and this was the result 
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
mysqlbinlog: File '<path>/mysql/slave-relay.log' not found (Errcode: 2)
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
(END)

Comment: The error that you see about the Errcode 2 is becasue you needed to change the path to the one that points to *your* relay log

Comment: There were multiple logs and I pointed to the latest one. I get this when I run the command:/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;

Comment: Well, if there weren't any updates in the log then that looks fine... but you don't need to check your logs - the issue is stated in the update in my answer - you've changed the schema name

Comment: This solved my issue..So the database names should be same on Master and Slave..Can you point me to documentation (easy to follow) that shows Master -- Master configuration using innodb. Thanks a million, you saved my day

Comment: What are you trying to set up?

Comment: A master -- master confuguration instead of master -- slave.

Comment: If your original problem was solved then you should accept an answer. Read up on Tungsten if you want multi master replication: code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCMultiMasterInstallation#Multi-Master_Installation